# XPath Query to parse all IDREFS in an attribute (containing possibly many of IDs)

Tags: xml, xpath, xpathquery

I need to come up with a query that gives **the products of the types from which no items were sold** Meaning if an item is of the type clothing, and no clothing items appear in the list of transactions, I need to display it.

This is my XML file (apologies for the super-Canadian-ness):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE store [

<!ELEMENT store (product*, transaction*)> 
<!ATTLIST store name CDATA #REQUIRED > 

<!ELEMENT product EMPTY> 
    <!ATTLIST product 
        name ID #REQUIRED 
        type CDATA #REQUIRED 
        price CDATA #REQUIRED 
    > 

    <!ELEMENT transaction EMPTY> 
    <!ATTLIST transaction 
products IDREFS #REQUIRED 
sumPrice CDATA #REQUIRED 
    >

]>
<store name="Gordons">
<product name="beaverCoat" type="clothing" price="100"/>
<product name="hockeyStick" type="equipment" price="30"/>
<product name="hockeyPuck" type="equipment" price="5"/>
<product name="icePick" type="equipment" price="40"/>
<product name="mooseMeat" type="food" price="350"/>
<product name="salmon" type="food" price="15"/>
<transaction products="hockeyPuck hockeyStick" sumPrice="35"/>
<transaction products="hockeyStick mooseMeat" sumPrice="380"/>
<transaction products="salmon mooseMeat" sumPrice="365"/>
<transaction products="hockeyStick hockeyStick hockeyStick" sumPrice="30"/>
</store>
```

**DESIRED OUTPUT**

`<product name="beaverCoat" type="clothing"/>`
because it's a product from a category (clothing) from which nothing was bought. i.e. no transactions include clothing.

**MY ATTEMPT**
I've played around with some queries but I just can't get it right. This is the closest I've gotten:

`//product[@type != //transactions/@products/@type]`

It seems like this should work - find all the products whose `type` is no equal to any of the `type` in all of the `transactions` however I am getting lots of errors.

I would really appreciate if someone could provide the solution with a little explanation.

Comment: Could you post the desired output?

Comment: @Imray Which is the programming language used? If you are able to handle an excetion then you can use the following xpath. This will throw an exception and you can catch it. If exception is thrown then simply it means the product is not there. //product[@type="clothing"]

Comment: @Vinay I'm using XPath 1.0

Comment: Are you allowed/able to do an XSL transformation before reading your needed values?

Comment: @Scoregraphic Negative

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use the [`id()`](http://www.w3.org/TR/xpath/#function-id) function to get the node-set of all items that *have* been sold, using it on the node-set of `products` attributes of `transaction` elements:

```
id(//transaction/@products)
```

and you can easily extend that to get the `type` of items that have been sold:

```
id(//transaction/@products)/@type
```

What you want is all products where the `type` is *not* in this set, which is given by:

```
//product[not(@type = id(//transaction/@products)/@type)]
```

Using this on your example XML selects only `beaverCoat` product node.

Comment: I wasn't far off, I was trying `//product[not(@type = //transaction/(id(@products)/@type)]`. Why doesnt this work?

Comment: @Imray I think it’s because you can’t use a function as part of a node  test as in `//transaction/(id(@products)`. You can _extend_ the result of the function because it returns a node-set, but you can’t just put it in the middle of a query like that.